# Trying to figure out a recursive counting program in Python

Tags: python, recursion, counting

```
def countSubStringMatchRecursive(target,key):
    """Counts how many times key is in string(string,key)"""
    x=find(target,key)
    print x
    return x!=-1 and countSubStringMatchRecursive(target[x+1:],key)+1
```

So this program takes a given string and counts how many times a substring shows up inside of it. So given the target 'banana' and key 'an' the function will spit out 2.

Im kind of confused as to how it does this. Does the x!=1 make it so the program only returns x's not equal to one? I assume the +1 at the end of the countSubStringMatchRecursive... in return is somehow counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is the index of the location of the found substring. If it's -1, it wasn't found, thus, the method returns 0.

In other words, it [short-curcuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit_evaluation) and doesn't evaluate second condition (e.g. it doesn't make the recursive call). Otherwise, it recursively calls itself using the position of the found substring plus one (so we can find next substring if it exists) and adds 1 to result.

Comment: Ah thanks for the help, didn't realize you could return a boolean value like that.

Answer (score 2):

As jhwist said, `String.find` returns the lowest index of the match. Therefore the recursion will only happen if the substring is actually found (otherwise String.find returns -1).

This is a very inefficient way to do this. Python supports this function, it is called `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`. Documented here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count.

So instead of

```
countSubStringMatchRecursive("test test test test", "test")
```

you would use

```
"test test test test".count("test")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually just have to do it this way for a problem set but appreciate you pointing out the most efficient way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[String.find](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html?highlight=find#string.find) returns the lowest **index** of the match. Therefore the recursion will only happen if the substring is actually found (otherwise String.find returns -1).

Answer (score 0):

I admit i don't know much about python, but this is an easy one.

The trick there is that last line.

The "return" first checks if x is not -1, wich would mean that the current recursion of this function did not find an extra "key" in "target", in wich case the clause after the "and" will not be evaluated and the function will return "false" (zero) to the calling function.

If "x" is indeed not -1, however, the second part of the condition (after "and") will be evaluated, and what that statement does is call the function itself, but it sends a substring of the currently evaluated "target", starting one character after "x" (the position of "key" in "target" on the current recursion). It then adds one to the value returned by the function and returns the sum.

So, the last recursion of the function returns zero (false), the one before that returns one (true), the other before that one returns two (true + 1), and so forth.

This may sound a little confusing, but it is the best way i can find answer your question.